# What is debug.log.old? It seems to take up a lot of space

Tags: debug

what is debug.log.old (please see attached image). It seems to take up a lot of space. Is it necessary to delete it? Or should I leave it alone? Thanks[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to delete it but if you want to save your space then you can delete it. Actually when we turn on the debugger then debug.log file created. It contains the warnings and errors of the code.

May be your development team have renamed it with debug.log.old. You can delete it or not its all depend upon you.